# Lost USDC after uniswap transaction

Tags: uniswap

I just swapped some weth for usdc on uniswap but the usdc never appeared in my wallet. my weth is also gone. I know was connected to the right uniswap because I swapped some eth for usdc before and it worked. Im not sure what happened. Id appreciate some help. thanks

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xadf441da02e3c5c29b2febf8193fbd48ecd03c0335995b9cefc45bbdea57ccdd

Comment: weth approval  https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd0972c36d8bb17a775d03eec030d0deb28732b9a2e4d73d3bfc4e13bb4bd3bc1

Comment: update: it looks like my wallet was affected by the dydx exploit. I revoked usdc permissions. Hopefully that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

According to wallet history, you did swap the tokens in uniswap and then these were taken by a contract.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd762e9619ae8e3f674ddc4defc025fce8e9ac1da0a700e2e877c9f5549512490

Seems to be related to dydx exchange so you may want to check that.

Comment: Thanks. I used dydx a while back. Wasnt aware of the exploit that happened until now. Does it look like my usdc was stolen? Im not real sure what to do here. Thanks